# Attribute error: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'space'

Tags: python, pygame

Attribute error: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'space'
What is the solution to this problem

Attribute error: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'space'

Comment: Is there anything more you can describe of your issue other than posting your error three times? Do you have any code and tracebacks you could supply? Are you sure pygame has the attribute space?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for this: `pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.SPACE]`. Very poor question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] and error trace. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
                                  ,---- "K_SPACE" insteard of "SPACE"
                                  v
pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]
```

**TIP:** Next time if you want to get answer on such question, give more information. Cuz we don't even know what is your code of what do you want to make.